# Multi-imensional Array based on Keys

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a simple way to take a single-dimensional array and convert it to a multi-dimensional array based on the spaces, or any character(s), in the keys?

```
$arr['foo1'] = 'bar1';
$arr['foo2'] = 'bar2';
$arr['foo3 tier1' ] = 'bar3';
$arr['foo4 tier1' ] = 'bar4';
```

and turn it into

```
$arr['foo1'] = 'bar1';
$arr['foo2'] = 'bar2';
$arr['foo3']['tier1'] = 'bar3';
$arr['foo4']['tier1'] = 'bar4';
```

Comment: where are you getting the keys from in the first place? can't you just make sure it goes in as a multidimensional array then?

Comment: I'm actually pulling them from a left join in a mysql query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can always do some sort of `foreach` loop

```
$newarr = array();
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    $output = explode(' ',$key,2);
    if(count($output)) {
       $newarr[$output[0]][$output[1]] = $value;
    } else {
        $newarr[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

That code will only work for one space but you can expand it to multiple spaces, something like

```
function pivot($arr,$delimeter) {
    $return = array();
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        $output = explode($delimeter,$key,2);
        if(count($output)) {

           if(strpos($output[1],$delimeter) > 0) {
                $return[$output[0]] = pivot(array($output[1]=>$value),$delimeter);
           } else {
               $return[$output[0]][$output[1]] = $value;
           }
        } else {
           $return[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $return;
}
```

Comment: I was kind of hoping to avoid doing recursive looping, but that may be the only way to do it.

Comment: @BlakeA.Nichols unless you know the maximum depth, I don't think you can get around it.